# HttpURLConnection has a "outdated browser"

Tags: java, https, http-post, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I'm developing an application in Java using HttpURLConnection that, first, send a POST to one URL and get the token that the site returns. And then, I use this token to make another POST in this same Site, but in another URL. When i do this, it returns **status 200** but in the response code is wrote *"You are using an outdated browser. Please, update your browser"*.
I  changed the **User-Agent** but it still doesn't working.

First request:

```
String parameters="parameter=example1";
URL url = new URL("http://example1");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", parameters + Integer.toString(parameters.getBytes().length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Second request:

```
String parameters1="paramters=example2&token="+token;
URL url1 = new URL("https://example1/form");
        HttpURLConnection conn1 = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
        conn1.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn1.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn1.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", parameters1 + Integer.toString(parameters1.getBytes().length));
        conn1.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        conn1.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");
```

The header response from the second request

```
Status 200
Server: Apache-Example/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Cteonnt-Length: 6923
Cneonction: close
Date: Sat, 27 Jan 2018 13:23:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=example; Path=/; 
X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1517059396002
X-Android-Received-Millis: 1517059396187
X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
```

Comment: try fiddling with your request headers, maybe use try a User-Agent that is known to work (copy the one that your browser sends, just to see if it works) or try omitting the User-Agent header entirely.

Comment: I did but still with the same problem, DutChen18